# Ada: Can you convert array elements into an enum?

Tags: arrays, enums, type-conversion, ada

I want to be able to read any number of lines from any text file, then store each line into an array, then make each of these array elements into one enumeration type. I am able to get the size of the array/enum before reading the file, then I can populate the array, the only problem is being able to specify the amount of elements in the enumeration type before populating it. Is there a way to do this? or some other clever approach?

Comment: Type checking in Ada is done at compile time. When you load a file at runtime, you are well beyond the point where any type checking happens¹, so it makes no sense to create an enum type at that time. You may want to describe your use-case. ¹: checks that need to happen at runtime have of course been compiled into the executable.

Comment: It is possible to declare types in an inner block in Ada, however those types cease to exist upon exit from that inner block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't create types on-the-fly in Ada, so the short answer is "no".

But there's (as always) a trick: You can write Ada source files for a package from your main program, where you declare an internal enumeration type based on the input data to the main program.  Then you can compile these source files to a dynamic library, load that library into the main program on-the-fly, and then call the operations of the package you just wrote.